# ag-grid-ng2 shows error " Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined in [gridOptions"

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the ag-grid-ng2 with my angular 2 project. I am following the steps which are available in the plugin site. Here is how I am implementing the example.

this is my component where I need the grid

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {MockService} from "../services/mock.service";
import {Hero} from "../mockdata";
import {AgGridNg2} from "ag-grid-ng2/main";
import {GridOptions} from "ag-grid/main";

@Component({
    selector:'my-home',
    templateUrl:'templates/myHome.tpl.html',
    directives:[AgGridNg2],
    providers:[MockService]
})

export class myHomeComponent implements OnInit{
    users:Hero[];
    selectedUser:Hero[];
    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
    private showGrid: boolean;
    private rowCount: string;
    private columnDefs: any[];

    constructor(private _mockService:MockService){}

    getUsers() {
        //this.users = this._mockService.getUserList();
        this._mockService.getUserList().then(users => this.users = users);
    }

    constructor()
    {
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
        this.createColumnDefs();
        this.showGrid = true;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getUsers();
    }

    onSelect(user: Hero) { this.selectedUser = user; }
    createColumnDefs()  {
        this.columnDefs =[ { headerName: "ID", field: "id"},
            { headerName: "User Name", field: "name"}
        ]

    }
}
```

here is my html

```
<ag-grid-ng2
        class="ag-fresh"
        style="width:100%; height:400px; margin-bottom:20px;"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [rowData]="users"

        enableColResize
        enableSorting
        rowSelection="single"
        suppressCellSelection
        rowHeight="26"
        (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)">
</ag-grid-ng2>
```

let me know what is wring with the code.

Comment: i have similiar issue.. may i know you found the solution and mind to share? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. But i used datasource. This error fired if i set datasource at the same time as the columndefs(method gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs() perhaps do something aasynchronously ). I think that when ngOnInit is called the grid is not ready yet. Try do this.getUsers(); in gridReady event handler.